# pandas: How to transform all numeric columns of a data frame into logarithms

Tags: python, pandas

In R I can apply a logarithmic (or square root, etc.) transformation to all numeric columns of a data frame, by using:

```
logdf <- log10(df)
```

Is there something equivalent in Python/Pandas? I see that there is a "transform" and an (R-like) "apply" function, but could not figure out how to use them in this case.

Thanks for any hints or suggestions.

Comment: Same thing can be done with pandas dataframe too. Its datatype allows scalar matrix operations like df * 2= (multiply all values by 2), or numpy.log10(df) = log10df.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Supposed you have a dataframe named `df`

You can first make a list of possible numeric types, then just do a loop

```
numerics = ['int16', 'int32', 'int64', 'float16', 'float32', 'float64']
for c in [c for c in df.columns if df[c].dtype in numerics]:
    df[c] = np.log10(df[c])
```

Or, a one-liner solution with lambda operator and [np.dtype.kind](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.kind.html)

```
numeric_df = df.apply(lambda x: np.log10(x) if np.issubdtype(x.dtype, np.number) else x)
```

Comment: I accepted your answer as it provides this elegant one-line solution! Since I know in advance that all my columns are numeric, I can use simply numeric_df = df.apply(lambda x: np.log10(x)), without the need to test the column type.

Comment: @maurobio You don't need to use lambda if all your columns are numeric. `df.apply(np.log10)` will suffice.

Comment: @MohitMotwani That is true but in my experiences if you’re dealing with a huge data frame it’s safer to do type checking

Comment: @RexLow That's right. I was just responding to the OP's comment because he suggested he didn't need type checking.

Answer (score 7):

If most columns are numeric it might make sense to just `try` it and skip the column if it does not work:

```
for column in df.columns:
    try:
        df[column] = np.log10(df[column])
    except (ValueError, AttributeError):
        pass
```

If you want to you could wrap it in a function, of course.

If all columns are numeric, you can even simply do

```
df_log10 = np.log10(df)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [select_dtypes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) and [numpy.log10](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.log10.html):

```
import numpy as np
for c in df.select_dtype(include = [np.number]).columns:
    df[c] = np.log10(df[c])
```

The select_dtypes selects columns of the the data types that are passed to it's `include` parameter. `np.number` includes all numeric data types.

`numpy.log10` returns the base 10 logarithm of the input, element wise

Answer (score 2):

If you care for speed:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': list('abc')*1000000, 'B': [10, 20,200]*1000000,
                  'C': [0.1,0.2,0.3]*1000000})
df.head()

%timeit df.apply(lambda x: np.log10(x) if np.issubdtype(x.dtype, np.number) else x)
#1 loop, best of 3: 539 ms per loop

%%timeit
log10_df = pd.concat([df.select_dtypes(exclude=np.number),
                      df.select_dtypes(include=np.number).apply(np.log10)],
                      axis=1)
#loop, best of 3: 315 ms per loop

%%timeit
for c in df.select_dtypes(include = [np.number]).columns:
    df[c] = np.log10(df[c].values)
#1 loop, best of 3: 113 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks, although in principle I'm not worried about speed, you raised a real concern, because the lambda function had a poor performance (although in the version I am using I don't need to test the column types because I know in advance they are all numeric).